$\mathfrak{sp}_{2n}$-stable spaces
Let $\mathfrak{sp}_{2n}(\mathbb{F})$ be the symplectic Lie algebra over an algebraic closed field $\mathbb{F}$ of characteristic $0$, that is, the space $\{X\in M_{2n}(\mathbb{F}) | X^T\Omega+\Omega X = 0\}$ equipped with standard bracket of matrices. I want to show that the only two subspaces of $\mathbb{F}^{2n}$ that are $\mathfrak{sp}_{2n}$-stable are exactly $\mathbb{F}^{2n}$ and $0$ (a subspace $W$ is $\mathfrak{sp}_{2n}$-stable if $X(W)\subseteq W$ for each $X\in\mathfrak{sp}_{2n}$). To accomplish this actually I am trying to show a somewhat stronger condition: given $v,w\in\mathbb{F}^{2n}\setminus 0$ there exists $X\in\mathfrak{sp}_{2n}$ such that $Xv=w$ (the natural action of $\mathfrak{sp}_{2n}$ on $\mathbb{F}^{2n}\setminus 0$ is transitive).
The way I am trying to accomplish that is by rewriting $X\in\mathfrak{sp}_{2n}$ as matrices of the form:
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
A & B \\
C & -A^T
\end{pmatrix}
$$
where $A,B,C$ are $n\times n$ matrices such that $B=B^T$, $C=C^T$. In this way, writing $v=\begin{pmatrix} p \\ q \end{pmatrix}$ and $w=\begin{pmatrix} p' \\ q' \end{pmatrix}$, where $p,p'$ are the first $n$ coordinates of $v$ and $w$ in the standard basis, and $q,q'$ are the last $n$ coordinates. This way we get the equations:
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
Ap + Bq \\
Cp -A^Tq
\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
A & B \\
C & -A^T
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
p \\
q
\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
p' \\
q'
\end{pmatrix}
$$
One way to show there are always matrices such that this is always satisfied is by showing that, with the said conditions over our field, the natural action of symmetric $n\times n$ matrices are transitive on $\mathbb{F}^n\setminus 0$ (if that is the case, for $p,q,p',q'\neq 0$ we can set $A=0$ and $B$ and $C$ matrices that $Bq=p'$ and $Cp=q'$ and handle the other cases of $p,q,p',q'$ similarly) but I cannot see why this is the case.
Any help would be much appreciated.

I found a way. Let $V=\mathbb{F}^{2n}$. We don't prove transitivity, but the following: there exists $v_0\in V\setminus 0$ such that for every $w\in V\setminus 0$ there exists $X\in\mathfrak{sp}_{2n}$ with the following properties: $Xv_0=w$ , $X$ is invertible and $X^{-1}\in\mathfrak{sp}_{2n}$ as well.
To show this, let $v_0=e_1$. Then, using the equations above, we need only to find matrices $A,C\in M_n$, $C=C^T$ such that $Ae_1=p'$ and $Ce_1=q'$. Now, there is no restriction for $A$, hence we can choose $A\in GL_n$ invertible such that $Ae_1=p'$. By writing $q'=[q_1,...,q_n]^T$ we can define:
$$
C=\begin{pmatrix}
q_1 & q_2 & \dots & q_n\\
q_2 &    &   &\\
\vdots &  &I_{n-1} & \\
q_n
\end{pmatrix}
$$
so that $C^T=C$ and $Ce_1=q'$. Now, we define $X$ using with those matrices and setting $B=0$. By block multiplication it is possible to verify that:
$$
X^{-1}=\begin{pmatrix}
A^{-1} & 0 \\
(A^{-1})^T C A^{-1} & (A^{-1})^T
\end{pmatrix}
$$
is the inverse of $X$. Furthermore: $((A^{-1})^T C A^{-1})^T=(A^{-1})^T C A^{-1}$. Hence $X^{-1}\in\mathfrak{sp}_{2n}$ as well.
The rest follows easily.
